# How to create abuilder in a stateless widget class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dialog

Hi I'm trying to use aligned_dialog package from flutter to show certain dialog for my button in my separated class but it show argument type error co-related to the builder. How can I fix this ?

> error: The argument type 'BuildContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [tiket_kerja] lib\widgets\reusable_role_container.dart:172)

Here's my code:

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        showAlignedDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: context,
          followerAnchor: Alignment.topLeft,
          targetAnchor: Alignment.bottomRight,
          barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
          avoidOverflow: true,
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/logo/Information.svg',
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

I tried to use this.context but it still show the error. Can someone please explain the problem please ? Is it related to the stateless widget and not stateful ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have added context to the builder.. But Builder is expecting a widget

```
 builder: context,
```

use some widget instead

```
builder: (context) {
return Container();
}
```

Comment: then should I still keep the builder: context ? or I  can just remove it

Comment: Remove the builder: context and add the one in the answer. builder:(context){
  return Container();
}

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        showAlignedDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: context,
          followerAnchor: Alignment.topLeft,
          targetAnchor: Alignment.bottomRight,
          barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
          avoidOverflow: true,
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/logo/Information.svg',
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

try this:

```
 GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            showAlignedDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {

                          /// change this return widget to your 
                          ///widget that going to show in dialog

                      return Container(
                           width: 600,
                           height: 360,
                           child: SvgPicture.asset(
                             'assets/logo/Information.svg',
                           ),
                       );
              },
              followerAnchor: Alignment.topLeft,
              targetAnchor: Alignment.bottomRight,
              barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
              avoidOverflow: true,
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/logo/Information.svg',
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

in build you should put something that you are going to show in that dialog.

Comment: why did my other widget background becomes grey when I click the svg to show the aligned dialog ?

Comment: I update my answer